# Different input types in the same method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any idea which helps to overload method with different input types?
For instance,
in my code I have got two similar methods for `UILabel` and `UITextField`.
Can I use one method instead of two methods below?

```
+(void) autoManageLabelWithSameSize:(UILabel *) label;
+(void) autoManageTextFieldWithSameSize:(UITextField *) label;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration

```
+(void) autoManageObjectWithSameSize:(id) obj;
```

Definition

```
+(void) autoManageObjectWithSameSize:(id) obj{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        // Label
    }
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        // TextField
    }

}
```

Comment: is it possible to set restrictions on input types: just (UILabel *) or (UITextField *) ? That is, if I set (UIView *) it compiles with no error.

Comment: id type is like Object type in java. It will accept eerything

Comment: it will accept. but we have written conditions for label and textfield only. So no action will be performed